# How to remove extra puncuation marks during saving forms data in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

when ever i add data to the form i got extra puncuation marks in the value as shown in the image.

for example - name = xyz
while saving i get name = ('xyz',)

[This image is for refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADvub.png)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the comma you are putting after name and other field you are defining variables and that doesn't need comma .